# Finding out size of Data lake analytics / USQL DB

Tags: u-sql

How can I find size of Data lake analytics / USQL DB ?

I can't find any information on it in catalog views, portal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not (yet) available. Please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Until then, you can find the information of the data size of a U-SQL table or database that is allocated in the `/catalog` folder on the ADLS account by using the `usql.databases` etc. catalog views. You can use the views to find the GUIDs that are used as folder names. Then once you have the folders, you can look at the file sizes and add them up.